# python type hints for decorators using TypeVar/generics and intermediary type variables

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to figure out a nice way of doing type hints for a decorator.  Here's a simplified/minimal example.  The decorator is called `@stringify_input` and it converts the inputs of the decorated function to strings:

```py
@stringify_input
def two_things(x: str) -> float:
    return float(x + x)

assert two_things(1) == 11.0


# implementation with no hints:
def stringify_input(fn):
    def inner(thing: int):
        return fn(str(thing))
    return inner
```

Say I don't know in advance what the decorated function returns, but I know my decorator doesn't change it.  currently the undecorated functon returns a `float`, so the decorated one should too.  I've figured out how to do that with `TypeVar`:

```py
# types check
T = TypeVar("T")

def stringify_input(fn: Callable[[str], T]) -> Callable[[int], T]:
    def inner(thing: int) -> T:
        return fn(str(thing))
    return inner
```

here's my question:  those `Callable[....]` hints are hard to read, they'd be easier to understand if they had names (my IRL decorators are more complex).  so i try this:

```py
StringFn = Callable[[str], T]
IntFn = Callable[[int], T]

def stringify_input(fn: StringFn) -> IntFn:
    def inner(thing: int) -> T:
        return fn(str(thing))   # Returning Any from function declared to return 'T'
    return inner
```

but that doesn't type check:

```
Returning Any from function declared to return 'T'
```

why is mypy unhappy with that?  i literally just extracted the two expressions!  something about how `TypeVar` works?

Comment: Not appropriate for answer, but perhaps a useful comparison: Moving ``Callable[[str], T]`` outside of ``stringify_input`` is like moving ``float(x + x)`` outside of ``two_things`` – it is the same expression *but in a different scope*.

Answer (score 4):

The `TypeVar` has been split to *several* type variables of same name in different scopes. Declare all expressions to use `T` of the same scope.

```py
# TypeVar scope equals function scope
def stringify_input(fn: StringFn[T]) -> IntFn[T]:
    def inner(thing: int) -> T:
       ...
```

---

While TypeVars are usually declared globally, [their substitution happens in a fixed scope](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#scoping-rules-for-type-variables). For example, one can use the same TypeVar in two functions to mean separate actual type substitutions.

```py
T = TypeVar('T')

def foo(a: T): ...
def bar(b: T): ...

foo("bar!")   # T -> str
bar(b"foo!")  # T -> bytes
```

By moving the types outside of the function, there are three scopes with separate meaning for `T`.

```py
StringFn = Callable[[str], T]    # T1
IntFn = Callable[[int], T]       # T2

def stringify_input(fn: StringFn) -> IntFn:
    def inner(thing: int) -> T:  # T3
        ...
    return inner
```

Since both `StringFn` and `IntFn` have a free TypeVar, they can be parameterised by a TypeVar of another context. Parameterise them by the `T` *of the function scope* to show that all of `StringFn`, `IntFn` and `inner` are parameterised by the same `T`:

```py
def stringify_input(fn: StringFn[T]) -> IntFn[T]:
    def inner(thing: int) -> T:
       ...
```

Comment: make sense!  thanks v much for the detailed explanation.
how do i define `StringFn` so that it takes a `[T]` argument tho?

Comment: @hwjp You already did but making it a type alias with one unbound TypeVar, namely ``T``. (I realise it's confusing to have so many ``T``'s.)

Comment: woa.  so I do `StringFn = Callable[[str], T]`  and then later i can do `StringFn[T]`, just by magic, to say i want to bind T in that context?  it's effectively doing `Callable[[str], T][T]`??? and that "just works"?  (i mean, it looks like it does when i try it :-). is that documented anywhere?